# Is there a specific way to conditionally add within a column in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is there a specific way to conditionally add within a column in PowerBI?

Sample data:

```
Lang|Book_Type|Number|Book_Type (groups)
------------------------
A   |  B1     |  2   | B1
------------------------
B   |  B1     |  2   | B1
------------------------
C   |  B1     |  3   | B1
------------------------
A   |  B2     |  4   | B2
------------------------
B   |  B2     |  2   | B2
------------------------
A   |  B3     |  2   | B3
------------------------
A   |  B4     |  2   | B4
------------------------
B   |  B4     |  5   | B4
------------------------
```

So, what I want to do is that I want a 5th column, wherein corresponding to each row, I have the total number of books in that type, i.e., alongside row 1,2 and 3, in the 5th column, I would want: 7(=2+2+3), and alongside row 4 and 5, in the 5th column, I would want: 6(=4+2). I also tried grouping, but it's still the same. Is there a way to do this in DAX? I tried the following code, but it gives a circular dependency error.

```
SUMX (
    'Book_store',
    IF (
         ( Book_store[Book_Type] = Book_store[Book_Type (groups)] ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Book_store'[Number] ) ),
        BLANK ()
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is a circular dependency is that you are calling the entire table as part of the definition of the new column in the first argument of SUMX (which includes the column you're adding... but you can't reference something you haven't yet created).

A better approach might look like this

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Book_store[Number] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Book_store, Book_store[Book_type (groups)] )
)
```

This tells it to sum the Number column ignoring all columns *except* the one specified.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. It solved the problem. It would be great if you could explain the functioning of ALLEXCEPT and how it works in the code.

Comment: My final sentence was an attempt at that but a complete explanation is more involved and requires additional reading to fully understand. [ALLEXCEPT](https://dax.guide/allexcept/) removes the filter context produced from the row context via the [context transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) induced by CALCULATE, with the exception of the column(s) specified (where the context is preserved).