# SUMIFS in power bi's power query with two different tables and no primary key

Tags: powerbi, dax

**I am trying to derive a column from a data source in Power BI which calculates via SUMIFS function.**

Here is what I am trying:

[image: Problem statement]

I have created a new column with the following code:

[image: Code implemented]

It is giving me a circular dependency error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559662/

Comment: Hi, can you post the DAX forumla as text instead than image? You can use the button to format the code as "code sample", the {} button

Comment: This error might be caused by another already existing calculated column, do you have other calculated columns in the referred tables?

Comment: No I have calculated any measure as such